# Using CopyOnWriteArrayList in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I am studying `java.util.concurrent` now. I am trying to understand  `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

As I understood this class looks like `ArrayList`, but thread-safe. This class is very useful if you have a lot of reading and less writing.

Here is my example. How can I use it (just for study purpose)?

Can I use it that way?

```
package Concurrency;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Entry {
    private static int count;
    private final int index = count++;
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                    "index:%-3d thread:%-3d", 
                    index, 
                    Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
    }

}

class Reader implements Runnable {
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Entry> list;
    Reader(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Entry> list) { this.list = list; }
    public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    if(!list.isEmpty())
                        System.out.println("-out " + list.remove(0));
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
    }
}


class Writer implements Runnable {
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Entry> list;
    Writer(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Entry> list) { this.list = list; }
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                Entry tmp = new Entry();
                System.out.println("+in  " + tmp);
                list.add(tmp);
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

public class FourtyOne {
    static final int nThreads = 7;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<Entry> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
        exec.submit(new Writer(list));
        for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
            exec.submit(new Reader(list));
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Comment: A lot of reading and _almost no writing_.  It's simple, really.  Whenever your code calls a method that would modify the list, that method makes a copy of the array, it modifies its copy, and then it swaps the new copy for the old with a single atomic operation.  If any other thread tries to access the list at the same time, the other thread will either access the old version or the new version, but it is guaranteed to never access a version that is in some invalid, in-between state.

Comment: You are using an ExecutorService (i.e., a thread pool) to execute tasks that never end (`while (true) ...`).  Don't do that.  I'm not saying it won't work, but that is not what thread pools are for.  I would use `new Thread(...)` or `threadFactory.newThread(...)` to make a thread that never ends.

Comment: Your consumer (Reader) blindly trusts that if `list.isEmpty()` returns true, then the list will have something in it.  That's a naive assumption.  It will be true when there is only one consumer, but in many systems, there is more than one consumer.  You should get in the habit of writing consumer code that will not throw a NullPointerException if the event that woke it up has already been serviced by some other consumer thread.

Comment: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is thread-safe too, and it might be a better fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for answers. Frankly I don't like approach `(while(true))`. Maybe it's better to use `while(!Thread.interrupted)` or something like that. Also i understood that `list.isEmpty()` would return true when the list will have something. Can I comment `if(!list.isEmpty?)` ? Or I can handle it by  a different delay `sleep()` ?

Comment: I think `synchronized(list) { ... }`  is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note in your example your one writer is writing at 10x the speed of a given reader, causing a lot of copies to be made. Also note that your reader(s) are performing a write operation (`remove()`) upon the list as well.

Under this situation, you are writing to the list at a astonishingly high rate causing severe performance issues as large amounts of memory is being used everytime you update this list.

CopyOnWriteArrayList is only used when synchronization overheads are an issue and the ratio of reads vs structural modification is high. The cost of a total array copy is amortized by the performance gains seen when one or more readers try to access the list at the same time. This contrasts that of a traditional synchronized list where each access (read or write) is controlled under some mutex such that only one thread can perform some operation upon the list at once.

If a simple thread-safe list is required, consider synchronized list as provided by `Collections.synchronizedList()`.

Please also note:

```
if(!list.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("-out " + list.remove(0));
}
```

is not effective programming as there is no guarantee the list will **not** be empty after the if statement evaluates. To guarantee consistent effect, you'd need to either directly check the return value of `list.remove()` or wrap the whole segment in a `synchronized` block (defeating the purpose of using a thread-safe structure).

The `remove()` call, being a structurally modifying call should also be replaced a method like `get()` to ensure no structural modifications are being done whilst the data is being read.

In all, I believe the CopyOnWriteArrayList need only be used in a very specific way and only when traditional synchronization becomes unacceptably slow. Whilst your example may work fine on your own computer, scaling the magnitude of access any larger and you'll be causing the gc to be doing too much work to maintain the heap space.

Comment: Thank you for answers.  I understood - I should use `synchronized(list) { ... }` or `if(list.remove(0) != null) { ... }` .

Comment: @Alex Note if you use `synchronized(list){ ... }` you no longer need a thread-safe structure. As long as you consistently use `synchronized(list){ ... }` for every access (read **and** write), you can use faster "non-thread safe" objects such as ArrayList directly.

Comment: Ok. Do you think it will be faster instead of using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` ?

Comment: @Alex Depends on your requirements: writer/reader ratio; write/read frequency and write/read concurrency level and size. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` should really not ever be used alongside explicit synchronization as it represents significant cost to write compared to `ArrayList`. And the advantages of fast read speed are completely negated by explicit synchronization. If you feel something like a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is along the lines of what you need, try a `ArrayList` synchronized under a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.